# Will the master know the data on workers/nodes in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

I try to deploy a set of k8s on the cloud, there are two options:the masters are in trust to the cloud provider or maintained by myself.
so i wonder about that if the masters in trust will leak the data on workers?
Shortly, will the master know the data on workers/nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abstractions in Kubernetes are very well defined with clear boundaries. You have to understand the concept of Volumes first. As defined [here](http://kubernetesbyexample.com/volumes/),

> A Kubernetes volume is essentially a directory accessible to all
>   containers running in a pod. In contrast to the container-local
>   filesystem, the data in volumes is preserved across container
>   restarts.

Volumes are attached to the containers in a pod and There are several [types of volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes)

You can see the layers of abstraction [source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/explore/explore-intro/)[image: The layers of abstraction]

**Master to Cluster communication**

There are two primary communication paths from the master (apiserver) to the cluster. The first is from the apiserver to the kubelet process which runs on each node in the cluster. The second is from the apiserver to any node, pod, or service through the apiserver’s proxy functionality.

Also, you should check [the CCM](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/cloud-controller/) - The cloud controller manager (CCM) concept (not to be confused with the binary) was originally created to allow cloud specific vendor code and the Kubernetes core to evolve independent of one another. The cloud controller manager runs alongside other master components such as the Kubernetes controller manager, the API server, and scheduler. It can also be started as a Kubernetes addon, in which case it runs on top of Kubernetes.

Hope this answers all your questions related to Master accessing the data on Workers.

If you are still looking for more secure ways, check [11 Ways (Not) to Get Hacked](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/18/11-ways-not-to-get-hacked/)

Comment: In the link  "11 Ways (Not) to Get Hacked", i got The Control Plane "......can read all the secrets stored in the cluster. " so what is the role of Control Plane?  <\br> And from your answer , you mean  k8s consider the data leak when design , is that right.

Comment: @touchingsoil The various parts of the Kubernetes Control Plane, such as the Kubernetes Master and kubelet processes, govern how Kubernetes communicates with your cluster. The Control Plane maintains a record of all of the Kubernetes Objects in the system, and runs continuous control loops to manage those objects’ state. At any given time, the Control Plane’s control loops will respond to changes in the cluster and work to make the actual state of all the objects in the system match the desired state that you provided. Yes, there are all measures(abstractions) taken to avoid data leak.

Comment: So if the master is maintained by the cloud provider , the provider can access the data in theory and actually ?

Comment: Don’t think so. All the major cloud providers( AWS, IBM Cloud, GCP and Azure) has invested heavily in security and data privacy. You can always opt for hybrid cloud option where your K8s sits on cloud and data on private cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes the control plane can access all of your data.

Longer and more realistic answer: probably don't worry about it. It is far more likely that any successful attack against the control plane would be just as successful as if you were running it yourself. The exact internal details of GKE/AKS/EKS are a bit fuzzy, but all three providers have a lot of experience running multi-tenant systems and it wouldn't be negligent to trust that they have enough protections in place against lateral escalations between tenants on the control plane.

Comment: So if the master is maintained by the cloud provider , the provider can access the data in theory and actually ?

Comment: In theory, yes they can. However If you are storing your data on their hardware, that was always the case. This is just how public clouds work, you have to trust your cloud provider to not access your data unless you specifically request it.